# 316 stainless steel and high concentration, high temperature Hydrogen Peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety, explosives

I'm looking at doing some experiments with small scale rocketry and I need to find the right materials for this project, where I will be burning through lots of HTC (peroxide above 90% concentration). I've found this datasheet [here](https://www.industrialspec.com/images/files/hydrogen-peroxide-material-compatibility-chart-from-ism.pdf) that says grade 316 stainless steel is suitable to temperatures up to 48*C. Can anyone tell me whether its suitable for temperatures much higher than that, or at least point me in the right direction to find any research on the subject? I'm having trouble finding the data I need.

This is more for experimental purposes than any practical applications so the total mass of the materials used is a non-issue.

Comment: You better change your approach, as starting with [high-test peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-test_peroxide) strikes me as unreasonable, to put it mildly.

Comment: Umm... Stainless steel in direct contact with H2O2? You might want to read John D. Clark's *Ignition!*, particularly Ch. 4: "And  a  disconcerting  number  of  things  could  start  the  decomposition  in  the  first  place:  most  of  the  transition  metals  (Fe, Cu,  Ag,  Co, etc.)  and  their  compounds;  many  organic  compounds  (a  splash  of peroxide  on  a  wool  suit  can  turn  the  wearer  into  a  flaming  torch, suitable  for  decorating  Nero's  gardens)... "